# Error in 'Copy' command in command prompt

Tags: c#, copy, command-prompt, system.diagnostics

I am concatenating video files of mpg format using the 'Copy' command in command prompt programatically in C#. I am able to execute the command manually in the command prompt and it works perfectly.

```
Copy /b D:\\ccc\\out0.mpg /b + D:\\ccc\\out1.mpg /b D:\\ccc\\bMPGVideo.mpg /b
```

But when i execute the same command programmatically, it throws an error.

```
strCmdText = "/K Copy /b D:\\ccc\\out0.mpg /b + D:\\ccc\\out1.mpg /b D:\\ccc\bigMPGVideo.mpg /b";
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();            
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.Start();
MessageBox.Show(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```

The message box shows the follwing message

> **The handle is invalid
>
>   The filename, directoryname or volume label is invalid
>
>   The handle is invalid
>
>   The handle is invalid**

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You most likely dont have the rights to do so. Try running your application as an administrator. That said, why not use the .NET BCL for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D:\\ccc\bigMPGVideo.mpg` should be `D:\\ccc\\bigMPGVideo.mpg`.

**EDIT - as per comments:**

```
// create target file
using (FileStream Tgt = File.Create (@"D:\ccc\bigMPGVideo.mpg") )
{
    // append out0.mpg to target
    using (FileStream Out0 = File.Open (@"D:\ccc\out0.mpg"))
    {
        Out0.CopyTo (Tgt);
    }
    // append out1.mpg to target
    using (FileStream Out1 = File.Open (@"D:\ccc\out1.mpg"))
    {
        Out1.CopyTo (Tgt);
    }
}
```

Comment: it was a typo while posting the question. both of them works in cmd but not from the code.

Comment: When run manually in the command prompt, it does not make any difference when '\' is replaced with a '\\' before the name of the output file. But it throws another error when the same change is done in the command and run programmatically. The error thrown is:

        The handle is invalid. 
        The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: why are using `copy` for concatenating files ? .NET has lots of file handling code built-in that can do that...

Comment: @user841923: You could also try to leave the extra "\" out and put an "@" in front of the string. So you can at least make sure the problem has nothing to do with wrong escape characters. See http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/03/06/the-c-string-literal.

Comment: @user841923 please see my EDIT above... this code does the same as your `copy` with pure .NET code...

Comment: it is nothing about the escape characters.. tried all those combinations already..

Comment: then it is just a problem with permissions and/or other processes accessing/locking the files...

Comment: the files can b opened and played manually.. they can be concatenated also manually using the same 'Copy' command in command prompt.. 

I tried concatenating using the code you gave. But i could not find the 'CopyTo' function for the filestream Out0 and Out1. It said i'm missing an directory or assembly reference. I added System.IO. Am I supposed to add any other reference?

Comment: which .NET version are you using ?

Comment: i'm using .net 4.0 in vs express10

Comment: Have you added `using System.IO;` ? That must work because it is part of .NET 4.0 / System.IO - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx

Comment: Sorry, i'm using .net 3.5. I thought .net 4.0 will be taken by default.. Using .net 4.0 might solve the problem.. thank you.

Comment: The code you gave is working well for mpg files, but it doesn't seem to concatenate wmv files. Why is it so? Is there any other method to merge wmv files?

Comment: WMV files have a very different structure which you need to take into account to merge them - in worstcase even reencoding can be needed... if you need to merge WMV files then ask a new question here on SO